# Session attributes in JSP

Tags: jsp, session, web

I've been wondering and i'am new in making websites. Is it a good practice of having many attributes in my session? and Is it ok to have more than 1 session?

```
session.setAttrubute("mysession",Object);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"More than one session" really doesn't make much sense; sessions are per-conversation, which in general means "one per user".

"Many attributes in session" is a loaded question, because the actual issue is session *size*, e.g., how big are the objects in your session. This depends entirely on your needs, your resources, your session hygiene, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, about the size 2 example i have a class that have 4 classes inside and store it to session(session.setAttribute("mysession",Object);)

and the 2nd example would be the 4 classes is separated and each class i put in session(session.setAttribute("mysession1",Object1);,
session.setAttribute("mysession2",Object2);,session.setAttribute("mysession3",Object3);,session.setAttribute("mysession4",Object4);)

would the 2 session still have the same size?

Comment: @KerPPag Sizes would be close enough to not matter if it's all the same objects, although since there are more keys, it would obviously be marginally larger. Session hygiene is important, but without knowing any details, it's difficult to provide concrete advice.

Comment: right rigt. Thanks for your answers it helped me realize things.